# How to extract a tar.gz file

Tags: installation, downloads

I am new to Ubuntu and I would like to know how I extract a tar.gz file. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to have a great Ubuntu experience, then do not run an unstable development alpha release (13.04) and do not install software from tar.gz files when you are new to Ubuntu. Both can easily make you believe Ubuntu is unstable, which it is not.

Answer (score 33):

```
tar -xzf [filename]
```

will extract. To see the contents before extractring try `tar -tvzf [filename]`

Comment: Do I have to put the filename in brackets?

Comment: no, you do not need the brackets.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the graphical tools, file roller, or the command line.

[image: file roller]

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/File%20Roller

Or the command line:

```
tar xzvf file.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

**Right click** on the tar.gz file and select the **extract here** option from the drop-down menu, and it will be extracted on the same folder as the compressed file.