# Terminal commands

Tags: command-line

I have some questions about some Terminal commands:

1. Why must you do `sudo apt-get update` before installing an program or after downloading something? Does it update Ubuntu then?
2. What is the different between `sudo gedit /location/to/afile.txt` and `gksu gedit /location/to/afile.txt`?
3. Why people don't use `-y` on the end of a command, like for example in `sudo apt-get install programx -y`.
4. What does the `-i` and `-l` (are there any more) mean in a Terminal?
5. How can I unpack any **.zip** or **.tar.gz** file in a Terminal?

Comment: 1. [What does “sudo apt-get update” do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/222348/what-does-sudo-apt-get-update-do) -- 2.[What is the difference between “gksudo nautilus” and “sudo nautilus”](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus)

Comment: **3.** It is a good idea to check whether `apt` is doing what it should or something utterly stupid (its very good at that) **4.** depends on the program - run `COMMAND --help`, `COMMAND -h` or `man COMMAND` to find what those options do for that command **5.** http://askubuntu.com/questions/262068/how-to-extract-a-tar-gz-file and http://askubuntu.com/questions/86849/how-to-unzip-a-zip-file-from-the-terminal

Comment: your fourth question seems to be unclear.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be split into 5 different questions? It's rather unlikely that others will have this exact set of questions, but separately they're all quite common.

Comment: No? It is one question?

Comment: These are separate questions and each can be answered: some have already been answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sudo apt-get update` updates the repository information of apt, so you can install the latest version of packages.

`sudo gedit` will ask you for a password in the terminal window, while `gksu gedit` prompts for a password with a GUI.

Most people like to review any changes they make with root permissions, that's why they refrain from using `sudo apt-get -y` and similar.

As for `-i` and `-l`, these look like parameters you would give to a command. Each command behaves differently and uses different switches, so without knowing the specific command, it's not possible to tell what these mean. Read the manual (`man apt-get`, for example) or try using `--help` with any command.

Use `unzip file.zip` to extract a zip file and `tar xzf file.tar.gz` to extract a tar.gz file.

Answer (score 3):

> Why must you do `sudo apt-get update` before installing an program or after downloading something? Does it update Ubuntu then?

No , it won't update Ubuntu. It just update the repositories and PPA's.

> What is the different between sudo gedit /location/to/afile.txt and gksu gedit /location/to/afile.txt?

[Don't open gui application as root through `sudo` instead of sudo, you have to use `gksu`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus). `gksu` package is not installed by default, so run this command `sudo apt-get install gksu` to install gksu package.

> Why don't people not use -y on the end of a command, like sudo apt-get programx -y?

Because people want `apt-get` to always propmt(ask for permission) before installing packages.

> How can I unpack any .zip or .tar.gz file by Terminal?

- `unzip filename.zip`
- `tar -xzvf file.tar.gz`